# In my Flutter project I face a "Parameter format not correct" error

Tags: flutter

```
Parameter format not correct -
C:\Users\gaura\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\geolocator_android-3.2.1\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\geolocator\GeolocatorLocationService.java:134: warning: [deprecation] stopForeground(boolean) in Service has been deprecated
      stopForeground(true);
      ^
error: warnings found and -Werror specified
C:\Users\gaura\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\geolocator_android-3.2.1\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\geolocator\permission\PermissionUtils.java:27: warning: [deprecation] getPackageInfo(String,int) in PackageManager has been deprecated
              .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
              ^
1 error
2 warnings

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':geolocator_android:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 9m
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                            547.0s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: It looks like you need to update one of your packages

Comment: When supplying console output, please always use the code formatting tool. I have made that edit for you on this occasion.

Answer (score 0):

> Be sure to provide all necessary permissions to use this package via
> Pub.dev.

[image]